# Connecting to SQL Server from outside of the Microsoft software stack

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I'm a software engineer in a Microsoft dominated company and now and then whilst between larger projects I am asked to create support for those larger projects. This will almost always involve some form of database interaction and being dominated by Microsoft technology our database of choice is of course Microsoft SQL Server. This makes developing support applications in non-Microsoft languages a real problem.

I've looked at Smalltalk, Go, Scheme and Factor and I always come to the same conclusion that it just isn't possible or worth the effort because ODBC support for those languages is just to fragile to be useful.

I've investigated the possibilities of creating a data access layer via a web service. This is not always the ideal situation though and with large amounts of data this can turn out to be a bottle neck.

I could clone the data and import it into a more open database system and then develop in a language of my choice. This seems like a very unnecessary step and also means that I am no longer working with primary data.

How are other C# .Net developers developing support applications that rely heavily on the Microsoft stack in non-Microsoft languages?

Comment: I write them in c#, why is that a problem for you?

Comment: It isn't a problem. I just want to investigate other languages outside of the software stack and what better way to do that than with a real world problem.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by going to another language?

Comment: I am not trying to solve the problem by moving to a new language. I am just trying to get a new perspective on the problem by using different languages that take me out my comfort zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going the ODBC route, you might consider using native drivers in whatever language you pick. This will probably "fit" better with that language's approach. For example, Python has [pymssql](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/) and cx_oracle which each conform more closely to the conventions of the language rather than trying to force it into least-common-denominator of ODBC. I'm not familiar with the languages you listed (and it's not clear if you're limiting this question only to those), but I suspect a similar situation exists there.

[FreeTDS](http://freetds.schemamania.org/) also comes up a lot in discussions of SQL Server access, but mostly from a Linux perspective.

Another variation: if you use something that uses the .Net DLR such as [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) or [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/), you get to use the .Net Framework and it's ADO.NET libraries while still applying a new language approach.

Comment: Native drivers would of course be the best solution and I did investigate this. In the languages I looked at then the native drivers appeared to be in worse condition then the ODBC implementations. :)

A good tip about .Net DLR route, it hadn't really crossed my mind to look into this and I have heard in the past a lot about the Iron language connections.

Comment: From the Iron range of languages it looks like only Python and Ruby are actively developed. So I think my journey can begin with those two.